# TelegramClient is getting an error (method was never awaited)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to send a message to a telegram channel for each new message in the API, But I'm sure that I'm not respecting the telethon documentation that I don't understand quitly.

Here is my code:

```
import requests, json
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync


class notify:
    async def tele_message(discord_message):
        api_id = 1111111
        api_hash = 'hidden-hidden-hidden-hidden'
        destination_user_username='gikou2'
        client = await TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

        entity= await client.get_entity(destination_user_username)
        await client.send_message(entity=entity,message=discord_message)

        await client.start()
        await client.run_until_disconnected()


headers = {
    'authorization': 'authorization-authorization-authorization-authorization',
}

params = (('limit', '50'),)
read_mess = list()

while True:
    response = requests.get('https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/292516924557099008/messages', headers=headers, params=params)

    for message in reversed(response.json()):
        if message['id'] not in read_mess:
            read_mess.append(message['id'])
            if message['author']['username'] == 'Noah Williams':
                print(message['content'])
                # client.send_file(destination_user_username, media, caption=event.raw_text)
                notify.tele_message(message['content'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you don't need to make ansync function for TelegramClient and if its import for you then you have to also use wait while using the tele_message(ur func)

Maybe i am wrong but you can try

Comment: I tried it and got this error:
raise ConnectionError('Cannot send requests while disconnected')
ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected

Comment: Cool, Solved by removing the async and adding client.connect()